# I2C_HID touchpad chip data reading

Tags: linux, touchpad, asus, hid

Recetly I tried to fix my touchpad lags with firmware update, but it crushed my whole touchpad. Now movement is inverted, and right click doesn’t work.

My touchpad is ELAN1200 04F3:304E, one of the worst supported touchpad’s ever.

However, I still have a hope.

I know that touchpad is being recognized as I2C-HID device, and if I could upgrade it’s firmware with a programm, it’s possible to read data and write data to toucpad’s chip.

So i’m trying to lookup for i2c devices connected but have no luck with i2cdetect -l.
My lsusb doesn’t show touchpad either:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b05:1869 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5666 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 09da:7dc8 A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Though xinput recognizes it:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ COMPANY USB Device                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ COMPANY USB Device Consumer Control       id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Consumer Control  id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1200:00 04F3:304E Touchpad            id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ COMPANY USB Device                        id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ COMPANY USB Device Keyboard               id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ COMPANY USB Device System Control         id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Keyboard  id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Wireless Radio Control    id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) System Control    id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=23   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=24   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ COMPANY USB Device Consumer Control       id=25   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Consumer Control  id=26   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The program I used to upgrade touchpad's firmware is here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1653456/comments/161

I'm interested in copying data from working touchpad chip and pasting it in mine. How do I do it?

Comment: (1) Go through `dmesg`, look for details how the touchpad is connect. If that doesn't help, also look through `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. (2) you may have to `modprobe i2c-dev` before you see anything with `i2cdetect`. (3) Fixing the touchpad, or even just "copying and pasting data from the touchpad chip" is not easy, and will require a fair bit of knowledge and reverse engineering, and from the questions you are asking, and how you phrase them, you probably won't be able to do that, but make it worse instead. So be careful.

Comment: I may phrase them bad because i'm a little at nerves right now. I know there is a way to do it, but what will I have to reverse engineer? If I am able to copy raw data and insert raw data, can't I just fix it that way? I know a guy with the exact same laptop.

Comment: Also I think there is may be some kind of a special filesystem with it's table, but, who care's if I just copy everything? I understand it's the last thing I should do, I've already emailed ElanTech (well I don't think they'll answer), and posted a thread on Asus rog forum. If I will be able to invert axis on a touchpad and somehow enable right click, I will be pretty comfortable with that. Any recomendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone seeking for the answer, I reached to ELANTech and they provided me the firmware. If anyone ever needs it, feel free to write me vlad.dalechin@gmail.com